# Log level conditional?

Tags: glib, vala

One can define messages in code using Glib functions like `debug ()`, which are only logged when the log level is set high enough, for example using the `G_MESSAGES_DEBUG` environmental variable.

Is it also possible to put code in some kind of conditional that's only triggered with a certain log level?

For example, I'd like the following code to only be executed when debug is enabled:

```
foreach (var object in list) {
 debug ("    object: %s", object.id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to pepper your code with debugging statements then you could check for the environment variable:

```
void main () {
    if (Environment.get_variable ("G_DEBUG") == "fatal-criticals") {
        print ("Debug code\n");
    }
}
```

An expert coder would suggest using a debugger to step through the code. This means you don't need to add extra statements just for debugging, but it is a bit rough with Vala. Here is an example. The Vala program is:

```
void main () {
    var a = "before";
    var b = Test.run (a);
    print (@"$(b)\n");
}

namespace Test {
    string run (string a) {
        return "after";
    }
}
```

Compile with:

```
valac function_breakpoint_example.vala --debug -X -O0 --save-temps
```

`--debug` includes line numbers for the Vala code in the generated C. `-X -O0` passes `-O0` to the C compiler so information is not optimised away. `--save-temps` keeps the temporary C files generated by Vala so the debugger can reference them.

Now run the `gdb` debugger:

```
gdb ./function_breakpoint_example
...enters gdb...
break test_run
run
# Program runs and then stops when Test.run is entered
step
# or `cont` if you want to continue on to the end of the program
```

You need to understand how Vala converts its symbol names to C symbol names. In this example a namespace is used, so `Test.run` is converted to the `test_run` function in C. `break test_run` tells GDB to stop running the program when that function is called.

You can set a break point using a line number in a source file, e.g.

```
break function_breakpoint_example.vala:9
```

There are a whole range of commands to get more information, like a full stack trace or print local variables. `info args` will show the arguments passed to the function, `p a` will show the contents of variable `a` and `info locals` will print the local variables. Some information printed will be more understandable than other information.

Another option, which again adds statements to your code, is to use a Vala pre-parser directive. This stops Vala passing the code through the whole compilation process if a condition is not set. For example:

```
void main () {

#if DEBUG
    print ("debugging...\n");
#endif

}
```

when compiled with:

```
valac pre_parser_directive.vala -D DEBUG
```

will include the `print` statement in the generated C. Without `-D DEBUG` that part of the Vala code won't be parsed and so it does not appear in the final output.

Answer (score 0):

[The default log handler uses some env. vars](http://soc.if.usp.br/manual/libgtk-3-doc/glib/glib-Message-Logging.html#g-log-default-handler) G_MESSAGES_PREFIXED and G_MESSAGES_DEBUG. You use g_log() or a [specialized version](http://soc.if.usp.br/manual/libgtk-3-doc/glib/glib-Message-Logging.html#GLogLevelFlags) ( g_error(), g_assert(), g_critical(), g_return_if_fail() and g_return_val_if_fail(), g_warning(), see g_message(), g_debug() ) to state the message.

Answer (score 0):

The officially recommended way* to make some code conditional on whether debug output is enabled, is to check the value of the `G_MESSAGES_DEBUG` environment variable yourself. If its value is `all`, or it contains the domain you are interested in, then enable your code.

There is no helper function for this — you should write your own.

*I’m an upstream developer.